# how to get camera width in unity

Tags: unity, c#

**Problem**

I have a spawn manager written in c# which spawns my game object, i use screen.width, to set the maximum screen with and -screen.width to set the minimum screen width for the spawning, but my game object spawns way off the screen.

I am using a portrait camera 2:3 instead of free aspect as my camera view, as i want my game to be in portrait mode

how do i make my game object spawn within the camera widths(max and min)?

**my code**

```
public class SpawnManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public int maxBalloons = 100;
    public GameObject balloon;
    public float horizontalMin = -Screen.width;
    public float horizontalMax = Screen.width;
    public float verticalMin = -5.0f;
    public float verticalMax = 1.0f;


    private Vector2 originPosition;


    void Start () {

        originPosition = transform.position;
        Spawn ();

    }

    void Spawn()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < maxBalloons; i++)
        {
            Vector2 randomPosition = originPosition + new Vector2 (Random.Range(horizontalMin, horizontalMax), Random.Range (verticalMin, verticalMax));

            Instantiate(balloon, randomPosition, Quaternion.identity);
            originPosition = randomPosition;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: If you're still looking for help on this,  can you please specify whether your camera is orthographic or perspective?

Comment: my camera is orthographic

Answer (score 8):

`Screen.width` and `.height` give you the current sizes of your game's display/window *in pixels*.

For positioning objects in our world, we want to work in worldspace units.

When you're using an orthographic camera, `camera.orthographicSize` gives you the verical half-height of the camera in world units (the distance from the center of the view to the top).

Multiplying that by the camera's width:height aspect ratio, `camera.aspect`, gives us our half-width in worldspace units.

So you can create your `horizontalMin` & `Max` like so:

```
Camera camera = Camera.main;
float halfHeight = camera.orthographicSize;
float halfWidth = camera.aspect * halfHeight;

horizontalMin = -halfWidth;
horizontalMax =  halfWidth;
```

For completeness, here's how you'd do it with a perspective camera that gets wider the further back in depth you go. For this we'll need an input `depth` value representing how far from the camera we want to spawn our objects, along the camera's forward vector.

```
float halfFieldOfView = camera.fieldOfView * 0.5f * Mathf.Deg2Rad;
float halfHeightAtDepth = depth * Mathf.Tan(halfFieldOfView);
float halfWidthAtDepth = camera.aspect * halfHeightAtDepth;

 // And the rest is the same.
```

Or you can just compute your desired position in viewport space (from (0,0) in the bottom-left of the camera's view to (1,1) at the top-right) and convert it to a world space position with [Camera.ViewportToWorldPoint()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ViewportToWorldPoint.html), passing your desired depth as the third coordinate. This will automatically handle both perspective and orthographic cameras.

Comment: error CS0236: A field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field, method, or property thats the error i get

Comment: @Kennedy Don't do this in a field initializer. Do it inside a method.

Comment: please how can i do this

Comment: Make a method, maybe one like `Vector3 GetRandomPointOnScreen() {...}` and put your logic that computes the desired point inside that method. Then call it when you want a new random point.

Comment: Vector3 GetRandomPointOnScreen()
 {

  Camera camera = Camera.main;
  float halfHeight = camera.orthographicSize;
  float halfWidth = camera.aspect * halfHeight;
  
  float horizontalMin = -halfWidth;
  float horizontalMax =  halfWidth;


 }                                                                                                                              what i did

Comment: It looks like you want to ask a new question. Please use the Question link for that, so you don't have to cram code into a comment.

Comment: i'm just not sure on creating the method, i put all the code into the method and i am still getting an error

Comment: Then post a question so we can help you with that error. Comments are way too cramped to get the full picture of what you're trying to do and what kind of help you need.

Comment: alright would do just that

Comment: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/159048/not-all-code-paths-return-a-value

Answer (score 0):

You need to use  `Vector3 randomPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(originPosition + new Vector2 (Random.Range(horizontalMin, horizontalMax), Random.Range (verticalMin, verticalMax)));` or you can try `Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint` as well

Comment: still the same result

Answer (score 0):

To find the "screen width" at the point of any transform, simply use this

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public static class ExtensionsMeasures {

    public static float NominalScreenWidthAt(this Camera c, Transform t) {
        float yFromCamera = t.transform.position.z - c.transform.position.z;

        return
            c.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(1f, 1f, yFromCamera)).x
            - c.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0f, 1f, yFromCamera)).x;
    }

    public static float NominalScreenHeightAt(this Camera c, Transform t) {
        float yFromCamera = t.transform.position.z - c.transform.position.z;

        return
            c.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0f, 1f, yFromCamera)).y
            - c.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0f, 0f, yFromCamera)).y;
    }
```

Note that, of course, any such extension must work with **any** camera projection ...

conventional, orthographic or some custom frustum shape.

An example of using the call,

```
    layers = new List<Transform>();
    foreach (Transform t in transform) {

        layers.Add(t);
        float widthOfLayer = t.GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds.size.x;
        float widthOfScreenThere = Camera.main.NominalScreenWidthAt(t);
        Debug.Log("w layer, screen " + widthOfLayer + " " + widthOfScreenThere);
```

(Footnote - generally, avoid using Unity's hokey "Camera.main"; of course, you'd have the specific camera in question in a variable somehow.)

In almost all scrolling-type games (whether 2D, 3D or anything else) when the game launches you have the difficult issue of what to do about different physical device aspect ratios. (Players on wider screens will "see enemies sooner" that players on narrower screens, so to speak.)  Whatever strategy you adopt to solve this difficult issue, the first step is always getting the screen width/height (at the position of your enemies, background, or whatever the case may be) and then adopting your approach to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

After looking around for some confirmation about something, under the hood, similar to this, I found my answer and though I could share it here (as this is one of the top result on google while looking this up).

While I can't tell if this was available over 4 years ago, at least in the recent version of Unity, you can get the "actual" pixel-width of any camera by the use of [pixelHeight](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-pixelHeight.html) and [pixelWidth](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-pixelWidth.html) as well as [pixelRect](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-pixelRect.html). (A camera's rect value allows you to get the position of each corner of a camera in screen space.)

This works regardless of if you're using the Perspective or Orthographic camera view.

By using [ScreenPointToRay](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenPointToRay.html), once you know the pixel width and height of the camera's viewport, you can get the 3D coordinates of all 4 corners of the camera viewport at any given distance you might need. (You only need 2 corners, but you can still use the 2 others for the sake of making it easier to remember/read.)

A good note about ScreenPointToRay is that it automatically takes into consideration if the camera is orthographic or not so you don't have to scratch your head regarding angles and field of view or whatever.

Then it's only a matter of setting the rules of either spawning the stuff within the 4 corners (between the X and Y of both the bottom-left and top-right corners for example). If someone else want to spawn stuff just outside of the viewport, you can set up the 4 directional zone (just outside of the viewport) by first selecting one of the 4 direction (at each spawn) and then, on the selected side, determine the position slightly outside of the camera's viewport's position.