# not all code paths return a value

Tags: unity, c#

I created a method in my spawn manager trying to get the maximum and minimum with of spawn to be within the screen but i keep on getting the error

> error CS0161: `SpawnManager.GetRandomPointOnScreen()': not all code
>   paths return a value

does anyone have an idea as to what might be causing this error

```
 Vector3 GetRandomPointOnScreen()
        {

            Camera camera = Camera.main;
            float halfHeight = camera.orthographicSize;
            float halfWidth = camera.aspect * halfHeight;

            float horizontalMin = -halfWidth;
            float horizontalMax =  halfWidth;


        }
```

Comment: Simple Google search : [Microsoft documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0161) - [Unity support](https://support.unity3d.com/hc/en-us/articles/207479673-What-is-CS0161-)

Answer (score 5):

Your function declaration says it's going to return a `Vector3`, but you're not returning anything.

Add `return Vector3(0, 0, 0);` or the vector you actually want returned to the end and it will work.

Answer (score 4):

When you start a method declaration with `Vector3 SomeMethodName()` you're making a promise to the compiler: "I swear, by the time you get to the end of this method, I will `return` an instance of the `Vector3` data type!

When you don't `return` as promised, the compiler throws an error.

So, let's ensure we `return` a value:

```
Vector3 GetRandomPointOnScreen() { 
    Camera camera = Camera.main;
    float halfHeight = camera.orthographicSize;
    float halfWidth = camera.aspect * halfHeight; 
    float horizontalMin = -halfWidth; 
    float horizontalMax = halfWidth; 

    Vector3 randomOffset = new Vector3 (
              Random.Range(horizontalMin, horizontalMax),
              Random.Range (verticalMin, verticalMax), 
              0); 

    return randomOffset;
}
```

Then we can call this from inside your Spawn method from your other question, like so...

```
void Spawn() { 
    for (int i = 0; i < maxBalloons; i++) { 
         Vector3 randomPosition = originPosition + GetRandomPointOnScreen(); 
         Instantiate(balloon, randomPosition, Quaternion.identity);
    } 
}
```

Comment: can i delete the vector 2 from my spawn?

Comment: I would not recommend spawning with a Vector2, because even in a 2D game z-depth & order matters.